# how to make an event happen when click a button on HTML by using javascript

Tags: javascript, html, button, onclick

I am trying to make HTML print out "Germany" when you click the button. But it is not working correctly. Is there something wrong in my code?

HTML

```
<input type="button" value="click!" onclick="shuffle();"/>
<div id="output"></div>
```

Javascript

```
(function(){
    window.onload = function(){
        alert("welcome to my trip record");
    }
})();

var shuffle = function(){
    var target = document.getElementById("output");
    target.innerHTML = "Germany";
}
```

Comment: You have Doom event Listener.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You made two mistakes First mistake `<input />` this is nothing. Second most common "function ();", the ";" Is wrong

Your corrected code

```js
(function(){
    window.onload = function(){
        alert("welcome to my trip record");
    }
})();

var shuffle = function(){
    var target = document.getElementById("output");
    target.innerHTML = "Germany";
}
```

```html
<input type="button" value="click!" onclick="shuffle()"/>
<div id="output"></div>
```

I like to use DOM EventListener

```js
window.onload = function(){
    alert("welcome to my trip record");
}
document.getElementById("myBtn").addEventListener("click", function_t);
function function_t(){
var target = document.getElementById("output");
target.innerHTML = "Germany";
}
```

```html
 <input type="button" value="click!" id = "myBtn" >
 <div id="output"></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Remove the `;` from your `onclick`

```
<input type="button" value="click!" onclick="shuffle()"/>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try to use addEventListener for make event on button click

```
document.getElementById("myBtn").addEventListener("click", function(){
    var target = document.getElementById("output");
    target.innerHTML = "Germany";
});
```

here is the working jsfiddle:https://jsfiddle.net/jxjpzvvz/

Answer (score 0):

```
<button id='btn_click' type="button">Click me!</button>
<div id="output"></div>
```

use button element for buttons, not input type button. we are not in the time of html 4.0 ;)

```
(function(){
    window.onload = function(){
        alert("welcome to my trip record");
    }
})();

var shuffle = function(event){
    var target = document.getElementById("output");
    target.innerHTML = "Germany";
}

document.getElementById('btn_click').addEventListener('click', shuffle);
```

i'm fan of no js in the html tags directly, so i add a listener to the element